# Country list not displaying in sylius

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2, sylius

Below is the configuration I use:

```
apache 2.2.22
php 5.4.3 
intl extension enable
```

How do I show the countries in a drop-down list?

Comment: Can you please give us more details. Screenshot, which page are you on etc?

Comment: @umpirsky At the address page..

Comment: Can you link it on http://demo.sylius.com/ please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add countries in the admin area (bottom of the menu on the left) for them to show up during checkout. If you load fixtures during the installation of Sylius some country codes may be loaded (I'm not sure though). The demo seems to have lots of country codes preloaded.